# about adding a new column in mysql workbench

Tags: sql, mysql, sorting

New to coding/SQL here, I've encounter a problem when I try to alter following column on mysql workbench (table name: train):

[image]

I want to adjust this column as "conditions" is too repetitive. So I was thinking taking out only the necessary info in this column, copy the data to a new column "Weather" and then delete the original column by doing:

```
SELECT trim(substr(Weatherconditions, 11)) AS Weather FROM train;
ALTER TABLE train 
ADD Weathers Varchar(255)
UPDATE train
SET Weathers = select trim(substr(Weatherconditions, 11)) as Weather from train
ALTER TABLE train
DROP Weatherconditions
```

AND I got error in the update statement. How can I modify this code?
Or there another way to achieve the same by like splitting the column?

Ta!

I've tried substring statement and got error as well. so need some insight of how to do this right.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4286884)

Comment: 1) why don't you update the column in place instead of creating a new column and dropping the current one? 2) any particular reason for withholding the exact error message and leaving us to guess? 3) is it possible that you just forgot to terminate the alter and update statements with ; and therefore you got an error at the update?

Comment: Weathers is not as clear a column name as weathercondtions in my opinion.

Comment: yes, it's more intuitive to just update the original column than to create new ones. still figuring SQL out. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your update statement has extraneous `FROM` and `SELECT` clauses at the end which doesn't belong there.  Change:

```sql
UPDATE train SET Weathers = SELECT TRIM(SUBSTR(Weatherconditions, 11)) AS Weather FROM train
```

to:

```sql
UPDATE train SET Weathers = TRIM(SUBSTR(Weatherconditions, 11))
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked!  really appreciate it !

Comment: @HaiyLan Thanks, and welcome to Stack Overflow!  If this answer resolved your problem, then please consider _accepting_ it, by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.